# A reliable way to logically minify css?

Tags: css

To minify this:

```
h1 { 
    color: #fff; 
}
```

You would get:

```
h1{color: #fff;}
```

But what if you had:

```
h1{color: #fff;}
h1{color: #fff;}
h1{color: #fff;}
h1{color: #fff;}
```

Minifying wouldn't necessarily solve this problem. Nor would it do much about this:

```
h1{color: #fff;}
div h1{color: #fff;}
```

I tries [csscss](https://zmoazeni.github.io/csscss/) which points out duplicates. But other than that, I wasn't able to find a reliable way to strip out logical redundancies in css. IS there perhaps a tool similar to csscss or perhaps even a PHP library that can do this kind of logical redundancies?

Comment: If you have any familiarity with `NodeJS` you can use [css purse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-purge) to achieve this. It does exactly what you want and it's pretty easy to figure out how to use it.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, pre-processors like LESS and SASS automatically do this... Never really tried though, hehe.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend a technique or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: Hey coderama, we've updated our tool which does this as well as minifying and more: http://rbtech.github.io/css-purge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [css-purge](https://github.com/rbtech/css-purge) to achieve what you are looking for.

```
npm install css-purge -g // no needed if you already have it installed
css-purge -i style.css -o style_purged.css
```

Also if you have automated build process using `grunt`, you can use [grunt-css-purge](https://github.com/dominikwilkowski/grunt-css-purge)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [css minifier](https://cssminifier.com/)

By using the css minifier the following:

```
h1{color: #fff;}
h1{color: #fff;}
div h1{ color: #fff; background: #f00;}
h1{color: #fff;}
h1{color: #fff;}
```

Would turn into this:

```
div h1,h1{color:#fff}div h1{background:red}
```